# How can we get the difference of date days (current date and future date) through Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

We would like make some changes of my Check-in and Check-out dates, like if we select two dates (Check-in and Check-out), we just want to store the difference of days.for ex :- 16/02/2012 (check - in) and 18/02/2012 (check out), the difference of the dates is 2 days, we just want to store this difference in Text field called "Nights"(2 Days).

We are using JavaScript (datepicker codes) for getting check in/out dates.

Thanks

Rod

Answer (score 3):

```
(checkoutdate.getTime() - checkindate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}

//-->
</script>
```

refer http://www.mcfedries.com/javascript/daysbetween.asp

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method to calculate difference in minutes:

```
getMinutes: function (minDate, maxDate) {
    var oneMinute = 1000 * 60;
    return (maxDate - minDate) / oneMinute;
},
```

So you should just change minutes to days!

Answer (score 1):

it would go something like this you can use `onSelect` events of jqueryUIDatepicker to calculate the difference see if it helps my solution is based on jquery UI DatePicker plugin.

```
 var CheckinDate=new Date();
 var CheckoutDate=new Date(); 
 var diff=new Date();
 $('#checkin').datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       CheckinDate=datetext;

    }
    });

$('#checkout').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
   CheckoutDate=datetext;
   diff=(CheckoutDate.getTime() - CheckinDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24);


}
});
```

now you have the difference in variable `diff`

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkindate = Date.parseString($('hotelFromdate').value,dateFormat);
var checkoutdate = Date.parseString($('hotelReturnDate').value,dateFormat);
if(checkindate && checkoutdate && $('noOfNights'))
{
var noOfNights = parseInt((checkoutdate.getTime() -checkindate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000));
 $('noOfNights').value = noOfNights;
 }
```